# Python write to file:TypeError: one per line how?

Tags: python, io

```
f = open('freq.txt', 'w')

def format(value):
    return "%.5f" % value

formatted = [format(float(v)) for v in result]
f.write(str(formatted))
```

What is wrong with my code?
result is list with 240 floats,I want to write them to file one per line.

EDIT 
Yes as Martin pointed put I got file like this

```
['56337.19531', '48429.55859', '44960.00000', '41631.85938', '35788.30469', '33180.00000',
```

I just want numerical values.

Comment: No, the result is 240 strings. You never converted those strings to floats.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Currently you're writing a _'stringified'_ list to your file, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No,result.sort(key=float).

Comment: @ForceBru I want to write 240 floats into a file.

Comment: @milenko: sorry, what? What has sorting got to do with this?

Comment: So what is `result` here? You didn't share where that comes from. At least one of the values in that sequence is a string, not a `float` object, which is why you get your error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry,my mistake,sorting is different issue.

Comment: @milenko: `result.sort(key=float)` doesn't convert the values in `result` to floats. It only converts those values *for the sorting code to sort by*. So your original list is untouched (other than that the order is changed).

Comment: @milenko: write them how? One per line? Because right now you'll write the literal text `['3.42245', '4.41242']`, including the characters `[`, `'`, spaces and `,` in there (floating point values are samples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message tells you what is wrong: `value` is a string, not a float.  You just need to convert it:

```
def format(value):
    return "%.5f" % float(value)
```

You probably don't really want to write a list to a file.  You probably want each number on its own line.  To do that, you need to use `str.join()`:

```
f.write('\n'.join(formatted))
```

Even better, use `os.linesep`:

```
import os
f.write(os.linesep.join(formatted))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open('freq.txt', 'w')

def format(value):
    return "%.5f" % float(value)

formatted = [format(v) for v in result]
f.writelines(formatted)
f.close()
```

Comment: Works,but I want one per line.

Comment: So, if the writelines did not give one per line, then try this: f.write('\n'.join(formatted))

Answer (score 0):

I think that `result` currently contains a list of strings, and not a list of floats. Even if each string contains only a float, you must indicate to python that you want to consider them as floats and not strings. 
For that, you need to **cast** them: `float(val)` returns a float value from a strting 'val'.
So, your code should be:

```
f = open('freq.txt', 'w')

def format(value):
    return "%.5f" % value

formatted = [format(float(v)) for v in result]
f.write(str(formatted))
```

or, if you want to always cast the parameter given to the function to avoid further errors like this:

```
f = open('freq.txt', 'w')

def format(value):
    return "%.5f" % float(value)

formatted = [format(v) for v in result]
f.write(str(formatted))
```